# warning to use new asynchronous factory 'sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.create(...)'

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

Following the [openui5 tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee) with some deviations I get the following warning when I serve the dev version of the app:

> Do not use synchronous controller creation for controller
> 'sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.HelloPanel'! Use the new
> asynchronous factory 'sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.create(...)' instead.

In webapp/view/App.view.xml the HelloPanel view is referenced as in the tutorial, that is with:

> <mvc:XMLView viewName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.view.HelloPanel"/>

If I serve the production build generated with ["npm run build:ui"](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/) I don't see this warning. If I change the code to boot from the CDN, I also do not see it.

I have updated the local UI5 installation to the same version as in the CDN (now 1.80) but that didn't help.

What is the reason for this warning? Also, is it something I should worry about?

Comment: I guess it's because in production mode warnings and errors are not being logged to the console.

Comment: So the error might be there anyway, I simply won't get notified, right? This makes it even more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is implicitly called by the mvc:XMLView line above.

Class sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView does not have its own settings but all those from the base class sap.ui.core.mvc.View may be used with the constructor.

[Among them is "async"](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View#specialsettings) and setting it "true" removes the warning, like this:

```xml
<mvc:XMLView
  viewName="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.view.HelloPanel"
  async="true"
/>
```

Comment: same thing happens in the "data binding" examples in the tutorial, same fix applies

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3112. Give it a  if UI5 should load such embedded views asynchronously by default!