# Binding the id of an item via aggregation

Tags: sapui5

I have a NavContainer and I want to set the pages with a JSONModel via aggregation binding. In the end the NavContainer should contain a bunch of XMLViews with given id's (to navigate to them later) and the viewNames to load the views.

```
<NavContainer id="idNavContainer" height="16em" initialPage="{/oInitialStep/sId}" pages="{/aStepPages}">
  <mvc:XMLView id="{sId}" viewName="{sViewName}" />
</NavContainer>
```

This is the structure of the JSONModel:

```
{
    oInitialStep: {
       sId: "idInitialStep",
       sViewName: "my.app.views.init"
    },
    aStepPages: [
     {
       sId: "idInitialStep",
       sViewName: "my.app.views.init"
     },
     {
       sId: "idStep2",
       sViewName: "my.app.views.step2"
     },
     {
       sId: "idLastStep",
       sViewName: "my.app.views.last"
     },
   ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> Error: "__xmlview1--{sId}" is not a valid ID.

I tried replacing the NavContainer with a simple list, copying it from the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070), and the same error occured. It seems like it is generally not possible to bind the id using an aggregation. Is that correct and does anyone know a work-arround?

Furthermore, the binding of the initialPage of the NavContainer does not work. It seems to be the same problem doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do it by creating the pages in a factory function but I'd still like to know if it is possible using a template in the XML.

In the XMLView:

```
<NavContainer pages="{ path: '/aStepPages', factory: '.manufactureNavContainerPages'}" />
```

In the controller:

```
manufactureNavContainerPages: function(sId, oContext) {
  return new sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView(
    oContext.getProperty("sId"), 
    {
      viewName: oContext.getProperty("sViewName")
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This approach is relying heavily on synchronous XHRs which freezes browser's UI-/ main-thread during the requests. And according to the [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View#constructor), "applications should **not** call the constructor directly, but use one of the view factories instead, e.g. `(XML)View.create`". I'm afraid the approach dynamically creating views via a JSONModel needs to be re-evaluated.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I guess that has helped me too. Then I'll just define the XMLViews in the NavContainer with XML.

Comment: Also if you embed a view declaratively, make sure to add `async="true"`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63344834/5846045